# Asp.net Core Can't init Hangfire using mongoDb : listIndexes failed

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, hangfire

Hello I try to using Hangfire with mongoDb  in Asp.net core app

I have an exception on the Startup.cs when launching my app  which is:

> Command listIndexes failed: ns does not exist: jobs.hangfire.mongo.jobParameter

I tried to create manually the collections using the prefix (jobParameter, statedata ...), but then he tried to drop them and didn't succeed

This my code in Startup.cs :

```
            var mongoUrlBuilder = new MongoUrlBuilder("mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/jobs?authSource=admin");
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrlBuilder.ToMongoUrl());
            // Add Hangfire services. Hangfire.AspNetCore nuget required
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseMongoStorage(mongoClient, mongoUrlBuilder.DatabaseName, new MongoStorageOptions
                {
                    MigrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
                    {
                        MigrationStrategy = new MigrateMongoMigrationStrategy(),
                        BackupStrategy = new CollectionMongoBackupStrategy()
                    },
                    Prefix = "hangfire.mongo",
                    CheckConnection = true
                })
            );
            // Add the processing server as IHostedService
            services.AddHangfireServer(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.ServerName = "Hangfire.Mongo server 1";
            });
```

I am currently using :

- Hangfire `1.7.27`
- Hangfire.Mongo `0.7.27`
- Mongo.Driver `2.14.0`

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: do you have a `jobs` database already set up in mongodb ?

Comment: No before i was using liteDb

Comment: Hi, I succeed to resolve my issue by not creating the database in Mongo, there is still some exception thrown, but as i saw in an issue in hangfire that some exception are thrown an it is not a problem